# Table not found in SQLite in Windows Phone 8.1 universal app

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I am using an existing database with this code:

```
private async void CopyDatabase()
{
    bool isDatabaseExisting = false;

    try
    {
        StorageFile storageFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("Database.db");
        isDatabaseExisting = true;
    }
    catch
    {
        isDatabaseExisting = false;
    }

    if (!isDatabaseExisting)
    {
        StorageFile databaseFile = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("Database.db");
        await databaseFile.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder);
    }
}
```

When I install the app on the device, uninstall and then reinstall the app I get this error: `table not found`.

When I restart the device and install the error does not occur.

How can I fix this?
please help me

Comment: Your function looks fine. It's difficult to know what's causing the error without knowing more information.

Comment: Like, when are you calling this function? When/how are you opening the table? Have you checked if the DB file exists before opening the table (even if you called `CopyDatabase()` prior)? Your problem could be caused by something else other than the code you provided. Sqlite will not error on opening a file that doesn't exist, only once you try to query a table will the error occur.

Comment: I calling Function in `public MainPage()`

Comment: When I install App coping database and when uninstall app database deleted and catch not deleted and reinstall app , function thinks database is exist and do not copy Database. when I restart device catch removed and function coping database how can solve this ?

Comment: I learn my problem in databaseFile.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder); in this line don't copy good to localfoldee how fix ? How can help me?

Comment: Try this line instead `databaseFile.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder, "Database.db", NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);`

Comment: I test this but give me error : `An exception of type 'SQLite.SQLiteException' occurred in QuranOneAyeh.exe but was not handled in user code

Additional information: no such table: qurandata` I guess this error for this lines code :

       `StorageFile databaseFile = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("Database.db");`
        `await databaseFile.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder);`
 and my DataBase files don't very well copy when reinstall my app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this :

I insert `CopyDatabase()` function in `App.xaml.cs` Class with this work solved my error 
tanx